GridDB Installation: Python Interpreter Architecture Mismatch with CMake?
I’m trying to install GridDB on my Windows system, but I’m encountering an architecture mismatch between the Python interpreter and the CMake configuration. The error message shows:
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.31/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:233 (message): Could NOT find Python3 (missing: Python3_EXECUTABLE Interpreter) (found version "3.12.4")

It seems like CMake is unable to correctly find the Python interpreter due to architecture incompatibility. I’m using the 64-bit version of Python 3.12.4. How can I fix this issue to ensure that CMake detects the correct Python interpreter for the GridDB installation process?
What I Tried:

Verified Python installation and added it to the system PATH. Ran python --version to confirm the version is 3.12.4.
Used the -DPython3_EXECUTABLE flag with CMake to explicitly set the Python path, but the error persisted.
Checked that both Python and CMake are 64-bit versions and compatible.
Reinstalled Python 3.12.4 (64-bit) to rule out corruption or configuration issues.

**What I Expected: **
CMake should successfully detect the Python interpreter using the specified executable path or automatically find it if properly configured.
What Actually Happened:
CMake failed to find the Python interpreter and threw an error about a missing executable or interpreter mismatch.
